# Brew Install Snappy

Tags: homebrew, snappy

I'm trying to install snappy via Brew, but am getting this error:

```
->brew install snappy
==> Downloading https://snappy.googlecode.com/files/snappy-1.1.1.tar.gz

curl: (35) Proxy CONNECT followed by 1891 bytes of opaque data. Data ignored (known bug #39)
Error: Failed to download resource "snappy"
Download failed: https://snappy.googlecode.com/files/snappy-1.1.1.tar.gz
```

There is nothing at `https://snappy.googlecode.com/files/snappy-1.1.1.tar.gz`.  How can I get brew to point to the right place and how do I find where that is?

Thanks

Comment: `https://snappy.googlecode.com/files/snappy-1.1.1.tar.gz` this location has file,are you connected through proxy

Comment: yes, I am.  Do you have an idea?

Comment: when i hit this link i could able to get this file which is of 2 mb approx

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me

```
brew tap homebrew/science
brew update
brew install -vd snappy
```