# How to install a different snappy version in MacOS?

Tags: macos, homebrew, snappy

when I use `brew install -vd snappy` brew is installing snappy version 1.1.10. However, I would like to install version 1.1.7. Seems there are no instructions in the [official documentation](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/snappy).

I tried something based on this other [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29829458/brew-install-snappy) but didn't work out.

```
brew tap homebrew/science
brew tap brewsci/science
brew tap brewsci/bio
brew update
brew install -vd snappy@1.1.7
# Warning: No available formula with the name "snappy@1.1.7". Did you mean snappy?

brew install homebrew/core/snappy@1.1.7
# Warning: No available formula or cask with the name "homebrew/core/snappy@1.1.7".

brew extract --version='1.1.7' snappy brewsci/science
# ==> Searching repository history
# Error: Could not find snappy! The formula or version may not have existed.

brew install homebrew/core/snappy@1.1.7
# Warning: No available formula or cask with the name "homebrew/core/snappy@1.1.7".
```

Is there anyone able to install a specific snappy version on MacOS out there?